# Compute average value of a column with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Based on the famous example to create a new column containing the min/max/avg... value of one column, I was wondering how to compute the average value and then to use it as a float variable in a calculus ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the value? The sum of the values can be done via the example given on page 51 of `pgfplotstable` manual. You can also divide that value by the  `\pgfplotstablerow + 1`

Comment: Finally, I have solved part of the problem by myself... Here is the corresponding code.

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question if you wish.

Comment: The aim was so to compute the maximum value of a column, and only one value, to finally use it in the text.
The only problem there is the ugly "dataExternalA" used in the macro. I have not succeeded to dynamically the name of table as an argument

Answer (score 2):

The answer is posted by OP in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\newcommand{\maxVal}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\buffer{0.0}
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\dataExternalA\as\cellValue{\pgfmathsetmacro{\buffer}{max(\buffer,\cellValue)}}
}


\begin{filecontents}{dataA.dat}
1 5
2 3
-1 6
4 14
5 0
6 1
\end{filecontents}





\begin{document}

% Read

\pgfplotstableread{dataA.dat}\tableA
\pgfplotstableread{pgfplotstable.example1.dat}\tableB

% Draw

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=none] table[x index = 0, y index = 1]{\tableA};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=none] table[x = level, y = error1]{\tableB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Compute

\pgfplotstableread{dataA.dat}\dataExternalA
\maxVal{[index] 0}
The maximum for the first column of tableA is: \pgfmathprintnumber{\buffer} 

\pgfplotstableread{pgfplotstable.example1.dat}\dataExternalA
\maxVal{error1}
The maximum for the column "error1" of the 'pgfplotstable.example1.dat' file is: \pgfmathprintnumber{\buffer}


\end{document}
```