# PGFPlots: Calculating and adding averages to scatter plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, pgfplotstable

In my source CSV file there is one column per data series, so I use `\foreach` to iterate over all of them and add them to the scatter plot. I also want to add a TikZ node that marks and states the average in each column.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18,
  height=5cm,
  width=5cm,
  ymin=0,
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % load table
    \pgfplotstableread{
      typeA typeB typeC
      9     14    5
      10    14    3
      11    14    7
      9     14    6
      9     14    4
      11    13    5
      11    15    8
    }\loadedtable

    % get number of rows
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
    \newcommand*{\loadedrows}{\pgfplotsretval}

    % using pre-calculated number of rows
    \newcommand{\average}[1]{%
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\buffer{0.0}%
      \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\loadedtable\as\cellValue{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\buffer}{\buffer + \cellValue}%
      }%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\buffer}{\buffer / \loadedrows)}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\buffer}%
    }

    % calculating number of rows on the fly
    \newcommand{\averagetwo}[1]{%
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\buffer{0.0}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\rows{0}%
      \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\loadedtable\as\cellValue{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\buffer}{\buffer + \cellValue}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotstablerow + 1}%
      }%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\buffer}{\buffer / \rows)}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\buffer}%
    }

    \node at (2, -1) {Type A avg: \average{typeA}};

    \begin{axis}[
      xtick={1,2,3},
      xticklabels={A,B,C}
    ]
      \foreach \type [count=\ctr] in {typeA,typeB,typeC} {%
         \addplot [only marks, mark options={opacity=.3}]
          table[x expr={\ctr}, y={\type}] {\loadedtable};


          % (1)
          %\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, 1) {x};

          % (2*)
          %\edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, 1) {\ctr};}
          %\tmp

          % (3)
          %\edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, 1) {\averagetwo{\type}};}
          %\tmp

          % (4)
          %\edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, \average{\type}) {x};}
          %\tmp

          % (5)
          %\edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, 1) {\noexpand\average{\type}};}
          %\tmp

          % (6*)
          \edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, 1) {\noexpand\averagetwo{\type}};}
          \tmp

          % (7)
          %\edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[fill=orange] at (\ctr, \noexpand\averagetwo{\type}) {x};}
          %\tmp
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are two implementation for calculating the average of a table column, both based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252360. The first uses `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof` to find the number of rows once, the seconds counts the rows each time it is invoked.

Creating the graph itself works without problems. But of the various attempts to add the average on the starred ones work at all.

---

(1)

```
./mwe.tex:91: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ctr 
                , 1
l.91     \end{axis}
```

I presume this has to do with the internals of `axis` that somehow delay executing the code and it this point the counter is no longer accessible.

---

(2*) Circumvents this by expanding the counter manually and works but isn't even close to my goal.

---

(3) + (4) Result in an endless loop. When I interrupt the compilation, I get

```
^C./mwe.tex:90: Interruption.
\pgfkeys@parse ...uturelet \pgfkeys@possiblerelax 
                                                  \pgfkeys@parse@main 
l.90       }
```

Ok, so `\average` somehow seems to be a problem.

---

(5)

```
./mwe.tex:91: Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating po
int number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '1Y7.0e1]/ )').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.91     \end{axis}
```

For some reason `\loadedrows` is empty here.

---

The alternative average calculation works in this case (6*) but does not change anything about the previous errors. This is the closest I can get to my goal. Note, that the TikZ node outside of `axis` works just fine.

[image: Result of example (6*)]

---

(7) leads to same endless loop as (3) and (4).

---

My questions:

- How can I add a node for each data series that marks the series's average and contains the average as text. Preferably those nodes should have name accessible from outside `axis`.
- Why does `\average` fail in (6)? How can `\loadedrows` suddenly be empty?
- What is the reason for the endless loops when I use `\average` directly inside `axis`?
- (Not directly part of the main question, but related: How can I avoid the `{typeA,typeB,typeC}` list in the `\foreach` loop and grab the column names directly from the CSV?